# Resource class and null argument

Tags: java, android, mvvm

I have a mutable live data:

```
private MutableLiveData<Resource<LoginResponse>> loginRequestData = new MutableLiveData<>();
```

And i am using Resource class that provided from Google:

```
public class Resource<T> {

    @NonNull
    public final Status status;

    @Nullable
    public final T data;

    @Nullable
    public final String message;

    public Resource(@NonNull Status status, @Nullable T data, @Nullable String message) {
        this.status = status;
        this.data = data;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public static <T> Resource<T> success(@NonNull T data) {
        return new Resource<>(Status.SUCCESS, data, null);
    }

    public static <T> Resource<T> error(@NonNull String msg, @Nullable T data) {
        return new Resource<>(Status.ERROR, data, msg);
    }

    public static <T> Resource<T> loading(@Nullable T data) {
        return new Resource<>(Status.LOADING, data, null);
    }

    public enum Status { SUCCESS, ERROR, LOADING}
}
```

My LoginResponse class:

```
public class LoginResponse {

    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private int status;

    @SerializedName("key")
    @Expose
    private String key;

    @SerializedName("anonid")
    @Expose
    private String anonid;

    @SerializedName("username")
    @Expose
    private String username;

    @SerializedName("photo")
    @Expose
    private String photo;

    @SerializedName("isBanned")
    @Expose
    private int isBanned;


    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public String getAnonid() {
        return anonid;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    public int getIsBanned() {
        return isBanned;
    }
}
```

As you guess, i am doing a network request with this live data. Before the network request i want to set it to LOADING mode by following line:

```
loginRequestData.setValue(Resource.loading(null));
```

But i am getting following compiler error:

> error: no suitable method found for setValue(Resource) method
>   LiveData.setValue(Resource) is not applicable (argument
>   mismatch; Resource cannot be converted to
>   Resource) method
>   MutableLiveData.setValue(Resource) is not applicable
>   (argument mismatch; Resource cannot be converted to
>   Resource)

Why i can't pass null argument for `Resource.loading` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LiveData` you have defined expects an instance of `Resource<LoginResponse>`, not an instance of `Resource<?>`, which is the one you are providing. Try this instead:

```java
loginRequestData.setValue(Resource.<LoginResponse>loading(null));
```

This way, you make sure that the null `Resource` you load using the `loading` method is of type `Resource<LoginResponse>`.

Comment: https://proandroiddev.com/oversimplified-network-call-using-retrofit-livedata-kotlin-coroutines-and-dsl-512d08eadc16 can you check this, he is using same resource class and using Resource.loading(null) what is the difference between my code?

Comment: I am not sure what they are doing in this article, but I wouldn't trust all the code they provide to build and work flawlessly as it is – there might be bits that are wrong, it happens quite often. In your case, I think the error is clear. Did my solution work for you?

Comment: In fact, I just realised that they might be "cheating" with [this line](https://github.com/rygelouv/networkcall-sample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/rygelouv/networkcalldslsample/NetworkCallDSL.kt#L11) `@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")` (Or maybe not, but it looks suspicious).

Comment: So, did my solution solve the problem? Please mark the answer as valid if it did.

Comment: No i am getting two compiler errors: error: cannot find symbol variable loading
 and error: cannot find symbol variable LoginResponse

Comment: I fixed with: Resource.<LoginResponse>loading(null) If you update your answer, i will mark it

Comment: It has been a while without using Java for me. I updated the answer with the corrected syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there isn't suitable constructor for

```
new Resource<>(Status.LOADING, data, null);
```

Check if `data` can be null.